# Angular Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword add additional field

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I`m trying to implement Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword method, but i want to add one more field with name to Cloud Firestore. This is how my code looks like for now:

auth.service.ts

```js
SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign
            up and returns promise */
            // this.SendVerificationMail();
            this.SetUserData(result.user);
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message)
        })
}
```

signup.component.html

```html
<div class="formGroup">
    <input type="email" class="formControl" placeholder="Email Address" id="userEmail" required>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <input type="password" class="formControl" placeholder="Password" id="userPwd" required>
</div>

<div class="formGroup">
    <input type="button" class="btn btnPrimary" value="Sign Up"
        (click)="authService.SignUp(userEmail.value, userPwd.value)">
</div>
```

Any options how I can realise it?

Comment: Create your own data model for example myUser with extra properties and copy Firebase user properties like uniqueId, email etc to your own data model class instance and then set your data model to cloud firestore

Comment: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field name in document users/uId) @RahulVyas

Comment: You might need to convert the data model to Map for storing on Cloud Firestore. I haven't used cloud firestore but I'm using real-time database right now and I'm already doing the same thing which you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had (seems like similar to what's needed) sample case (it's using Auth service to subscribe with Firebase Auth and create new User in Rtdb (use firestore in your case) ) :

```js
 // ...
signUp({ email, pass, username }: { email: string; pass: string; username?: string; } = { email: '', pass: '', username: '' }) {
    if (!email.trim().length || !pass.trim().length || !username.trim().length) return throwError(`Email / Password / Username should not be empty..!  `);

    return from(this.fAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)).pipe(
      concatMap((fbUserCreds: auth.UserCredential) => {
        let { uid, email, ...rest } = fbUserCreds.user;
        return this.userSvc.upsertDbUser({ id: uid, name: username, email }).pipe(
          concatMap(_user => {
            return this.setDbUserLoggedinStatus({ uid, status: true }).pipe(
              mapTo({ id: uid, email } as Partial<IUser>)
            );
          })
        );
      }),
      tap((user) => this.userSvc.setCurrentId(user.id)),
      catchError((err: auth.AuthError) => {
        console.error(`[FbSvc->signInUser()]::::::::   ${JSON.stringify(err.message)}`);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

https://github.com/VovanSuper/IonicChat-firebase-functions-dummy/blob/master/src/app/shared/providers/auth.service.ts#L48